# difference syntax in class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have a questions about two different syntax of writing class constructor.

```
class Sample {
 private:
     int * p;
 public:
  // first way of writing the constructor 
    Sample() 
     {p = new int; 
     }

   //second way of writing the constructor
   Sample():p(new int)
    {}

 };
```

Is there any difference between the two different syntax? Or are they just the same thing?
Thanks !

Comment: As a side note: You shouldn't use `new`/raw pointers to instantiate class members.

Comment: Thanks very much !  As to the raw pointer, did you mean a smart pointer should be used instead ?

Comment: Yes., use either smart pointers or just a plain member `int x;`.